# Face Detection using Google Glass Enterprise Edition 2

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-glass, arcore

Is OpenCV the most readily available way to get Face Detection working for offline, on-device use case with Google Glass Enterprise Edition 2?

I see three Google-provided libraries, ML Kit, ARCore and, Android-built-in Camera API's face detection, support offline face detection. However, they all seem they won't work for following reasons.

(1) ML Kit doesn't work since it requires Play Services
G. Glass EE 2 only ships with vanilla Android Oreo 8.0

Glass Tech Specs noting Android Oreo - https://www.google.com/glass/tech-specs/
MLKit requirements noting Play Services - https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

(2) AR Core doesn't work because of the same reason, i.e. Play Services
ARCore requirements noting Play Services - https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/supported-devices#android_play

(3) Built-in Camera API for Face Detcetion is Accepted as not working as well
https://code.google.com/archive/p/google-glass-api/issues/282

Answer (score 0):

It looks like OpenCV may not be a good option after all since it's likely too slow on the CPU, and, hasn't been tested on GPU for the Snapdragon XR1 SoC that Google Glass EE2 relies on.
Reference: https://developer.qualcomm.com/forum/qdn-forums/software/fastcv-computer-vision-sdk/35734