# What are the available options for Face Detection using Google Glass Enterprise 2?

Tags: android, face-detection, google-glass, google-mlkit

My use-case is to detect faces (from continuous stream of input to google glass) I tried using [ML Kit](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/face-detection) but it seems it requires play store which GGE 2 doesn't have

Referring to this [Face Detection using Google Glass Enterprise Edition 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62069542/face-detection-using-google-glass-enterprise-edition-2)
Has anyone find a solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

There are other options that do not require Play Services such as [opencv](https://opencv.org/android/) but I wouldn't suggest doing any heavy work on a wearable device like Glass, I think your best option would be to use a remote service, for example [Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/cognitive-services/computer-vision/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ML Kit bundled Face Detection library? i.e. `com.google.mlkit:face-detection:16.1.5`

The bundled version should not require Google Play services. Only unbundled version requires.